# CHelper Codeforce/Topcoder plugin issue

Tags: java

I install the plugin CHelper for InelliJ IDEA (for MacOSX) and it doesn't work fine. I have a problem to compile a task problem, you can see the log in below.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /src/test/A - Maze.task (No such file or directory)
    at net.egork.chelper.tester.NewTester.test(NewTester.java:41)
    at net.egork.chelper.tester.NewTester.main(NewTester.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /src/test/A - Maze.task (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
    at net.egork.chelper.tester.NewTester.test(NewTester.java:39)
    ... 6 more
```

The **Event Log** : 20:12:53 Compilation completed successfully in 1 sec

My **chelper.properties** :

```
smartTesting=true
archiveDirectory=/src/archive
defaultDirectory=/src/test
extensionProposed=true
outputClass=java.io.PrintWriter
excludePackages=java.,javax.,com.sun.
outputDirectory=/src
author=
libraryMigrated=true
failOnIntegerOverflowForNewTasks=false
inputClass=java.util.Scanner
enableUnitTests=true
testDirectory=/src/test
```

Some Image to clarify my question/problem.

[image]

Can anyone help me to fix that issue in my config?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the output folder selected in your projects build path.  Are these uncompiled files in your src folder in your build folder?  I am betting they are not since most project builders will only copy over the compiled class files.  If that is the case you will need to Google the Resource folder that Eclipse uses to copy them to instead.

Comment: I am not using the Eclipse, and the others Class didn't need to be compiled to Main work, since the Main call the TaskA.class (A - Maze.task) it's will be work fine, then this is not the problem. About the output folder selected works good, you can see the error and don't accuse that. The problem is the IO cannot see the path to *.Task into building the Main.